# Displaying Percentages in a Sankey Diagram using D3 JS

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg, sankey-diagram

I am new to D3 js and trying display percentages on the sankey diagram by nodes. I am able to display percentages in the sankey but it calculates the percentage by total value. Any help is appreciated. 
Thank you!!

```js
d3.sankey = function() {
  var sankey = {},
      nodeWidth = 24,
      nodePadding = 8,
      size = [1, 1],
      nodes = [],
      links = [];

  sankey.nodeWidth = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return nodeWidth;
    nodeWidth = +_;
    return sankey;
  };

  sankey.nodePadding = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return nodePadding;
    nodePadding = +_;
    return sankey;
  };

  sankey.nodes = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return nodes;
    nodes = _;
    return sankey;
  };

  sankey.links = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return links;
    links = _;
    return sankey;
  };

  sankey.size = function(_) {
    if (!arguments.length) return size;
    size = _;
    return sankey;
  };

  sankey.layout = function(iterations) {
    computeNodeLinks();
    computeNodeValues();
    computeNodeBreadths();
    computeNodeDepths(iterations);
    computeLinkDepths();
    return sankey;
  };

  sankey.relayout = function() {
    computeLinkDepths();
    return sankey;
  };

  sankey.link = function() {
    var curvature = .5;

    function link(d) {
      var x0 = d.source.x + d.source.dx,
          x1 = d.target.x,
          xi = d3.interpolateNumber(x0, x1),
          x2 = xi(curvature),
          x3 = xi(1 - curvature),
          y0 = d.source.y + d.sy + d.dy / 2,
          y1 = d.target.y + d.ty + d.dy / 2;
      return "M" + x0 + "," + y0
           + "C" + x2 + "," + y0
           + " " + x3 + "," + y1
           + " " + x1 + "," + y1;
    }

    link.curvature = function(_) {
      if (!arguments.length) return curvature;
      curvature = +_;
      return link;
    };

    return link;
  };

  // Populate the sourceLinks and targetLinks for each node.
  // Also, if the source and target are not objects, assume they are indices.
  function computeNodeLinks() {
    nodes.forEach(function(node) {
      node.sourceLinks = [];
      node.targetLinks = [];
    });
    links.forEach(function(link) {
      var source = link.source,
          target = link.target;
      if (typeof source === "number") source = link.source = nodes[link.source];
      if (typeof target === "number") target = link.target = nodes[link.target];
      source.sourceLinks.push(link);
      target.targetLinks.push(link);
    });
  }

  // Compute the value (size) of each node by summing the associated links.
  function computeNodeValues() {
    nodes.forEach(function(node) {
      node.value = Math.max(
        d3.sum(node.sourceLinks, value),
        d3.sum(node.targetLinks, value)
      );
    });
  }

  // Iteratively assign the breadth (x-position) for each node.
  // Nodes are assigned the maximum breadth of incoming neighbors plus one;
  // nodes with no incoming links are assigned breadth zero, while
  // nodes with no outgoing links are assigned the maximum breadth.
  function computeNodeBreadths() {
    var remainingNodes = nodes,
        nextNodes,
        x = 0;

    while (remainingNodes.length) {
      nextNodes = [];
      remainingNodes.forEach(function(node) {
        node.x = x;
        node.dx = nodeWidth;
        node.sourceLinks.forEach(function(link) {
          nextNodes.push(link.target);
        });
      });
      remainingNodes = nextNodes;
      ++x;
    }

    //
    moveSinksRight(x);
    scaleNodeBreadths((width - nodeWidth) / (x - 1));
  }

  function moveSourcesRight() {
    nodes.forEach(function(node) {
      if (!node.targetLinks.length) {
        node.x = d3.min(node.sourceLinks, function(d) { return d.target.x; }) - 1;
      }
    });
  }

  function moveSinksRight(x) {
    nodes.forEach(function(node) {
      if (!node.sourceLinks.length) {
        node.x = x - 1;
      }
    });
  }

  function scaleNodeBreadths(kx) {
    nodes.forEach(function(node) {
      node.x *= kx;
    });
  }

  function computeNodeDepths(iterations) {
    var nodesByBreadth = d3.nest()
        .key(function(d) { return d.x; })
        .sortKeys(d3.ascending)
        .entries(nodes)
        .map(function(d) { return d.values; });

    //
    initializeNodeDepth();
    resolveCollisions();
    for (var alpha = 1; iterations > 0; --iterations) {
      relaxRightToLeft(alpha *= .99);
      resolveCollisions();
      relaxLeftToRight(alpha);
      resolveCollisions();
    }

    function initializeNodeDepth() {
      var ky = d3.min(nodesByBreadth, function(nodes) {
        return (size[1] - (nodes.length - 1) * nodePadding) / d3.sum(nodes, value);
      });

      nodesByBreadth.forEach(function(nodes) {
        nodes.forEach(function(node, i) {
          node.y = i;
          node.dy = node.value * ky;
        });
      });

      links.forEach(function(link) {
        link.dy = link.value * ky;
      });
    }

    function relaxLeftToRight(alpha) {
      nodesByBreadth.forEach(function(nodes, breadth) {
        nodes.forEach(function(node) {
          if (node.targetLinks.length) {
            var y = d3.sum(node.targetLinks, weightedSource) / d3.sum(node.targetLinks, value);
            node.y += (y - center(node)) * alpha;
          }
        });
      });

      function weightedSource(link) {
        return center(link.source) * link.value;
      }
    }

    function relaxRightToLeft(alpha) {
      nodesByBreadth.slice().reverse().forEach(function(nodes) {
        nodes.forEach(function(node) {
          if (node.sourceLinks.length) {
            var y = d3.sum(node.sourceLinks, weightedTarget) / d3.sum(node.sourceLinks, value);
            node.y += (y - center(node)) * alpha;
          }
        });
      });

      function weightedTarget(link) {
        return center(link.target) * link.value;
      }
    }

    function resolveCollisions() {
      nodesByBreadth.forEach(function(nodes) {
        var node,
            dy,
            y0 = 0,
            n = nodes.length,
            i;

        // Push any overlapping nodes down.
        nodes.sort(ascendingDepth);
        for (i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
          node = nodes[i];
          dy = y0 - node.y;
          if (dy > 0) node.y += dy;
          y0 = node.y + node.dy + nodePadding;
        }

        // If the bottommost node goes outside the bounds, push it back up.
        dy = y0 - nodePadding - size[1];
        if (dy > 0) {
          y0 = node.y -= dy;

          // Push any overlapping nodes back up.
          for (i = n - 2; i >= 0; --i) {
            node = nodes[i];
            dy = node.y + node.dy + nodePadding - y0;
            if (dy > 0) node.y -= dy;
            y0 = node.y;
          }
        }
      });
    }

    function ascendingDepth(a, b) {
      return a.y - b.y;
    }
  }

  
  function computeLinkDepths() {
    nodes.forEach(function(node) {
      node.sourceLinks.sort(ascendingTargetDepth);
      node.targetLinks.sort(ascendingSourceDepth);
    });
    nodes.forEach(function(node) {
      var sy = 0, ty = 0;
      node.sourceLinks.forEach(function(link) {
        link.sy = sy;
        sy += link.dy;
      });
      node.targetLinks.forEach(function(link) {
        link.ty = ty;
        ty += link.dy;
      });
    });

    function ascendingSourceDepth(a, b) {
      return a.source.y - b.source.y;
    }

    function ascendingTargetDepth(a, b) {
      return a.target.y - b.target.y;
    }
  }

  function center(node) {
    return node.y + node.dy / 2;
  }

  function value(link) {
    return link.value;
  }

  return sankey;
};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>SANKEY Experiment</title>
<style>
.node rect {
  cursor: move;
  fill-opacity: .9;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
.node text {
  pointer-events: none;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #fff;
}
.link {
  fill: none;
  stroke: #000;
  stroke-opacity: .2;
}
.link:hover {
  stroke-opacity: .5;
}
</style>
<Head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="sankey.css">
<h1> 
<div class="container">
  <div>Equipment</div><div>Resolution</div><div>Repeat_call_Flag</div>
</div>
 </h1>
</Head>
<body>


<p id="chart">

<script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<script src="sankey.js"></script>
<script>
 
var units = "Widgets";
var margin = {top: 10, right: 10, bottom: 10, left: 10},
    width = 1800 - margin.left - margin.right,
    height = 1300 - margin.top - margin.bottom;
var formatNumber = d3.format(",.0f"),    // zero decimal places
    format = function(d) { return formatNumber(d) + " " + units; },
    color = d3.scale.category20();
// append the svg canvas to the page
var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
    .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
    .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
    .attr("transform", 
          "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
// Set the sankey diagram properties
var sankey = d3.sankey()
    .nodeWidth(20)
    .nodePadding(30)
    .size([width, height]);
var path = sankey.link();
// load the data (using the timelyportfolio csv method)
d3.csv("sankey.csv", function(error, data) {
  //set up graph in same style as original example but empty
  graph = {"nodes" : [], "links" : []};
    data.forEach(function (d) {
      graph.nodes.push({ "name": d.source });
      graph.nodes.push({ "name": d.target });           // changed the name here
      graph.links.push({ "source": d.source,
                         "target": d.target,
                         "value": +d.value });
     });
     // return only the distinct / unique nodes
     graph.nodes = d3.keys(d3.nest()
       .key(function (d) { return d.name; })
       .map(graph.nodes));
     // loop through each link replacing the text with its index from node
     graph.links.forEach(function (d, i) {
       graph.links[i].source = graph.nodes.indexOf(graph.links[i].source);
       graph.links[i].target = graph.nodes.indexOf(graph.links[i].target);
     });
     //now loop through each nodes to make nodes an array of objects
     // rather than an array of strings
     graph.nodes.forEach(function (d, i) {
       graph.nodes[i] = { "name": d };
     });
  sankey
    .nodes(graph.nodes)
    .links(graph.links)
    .layout(50);
// add in the links
  var link = svg.append("g").selectAll(".link")
      .data(graph.links)
    .enter()
 .append("path")
      .attr("class", "link")
  .attr("id",function(d,i) { return "linkLabel" + i; })
      .attr("d", path)
      .style("stroke-width", function(d) { 
    return Math.max(1, d.dy); })
      .sort(function(a, b) { return b.dy - a.dy; });

// % calculation   
  var total = d3.sum(data, function(d) {return d.value});         // % data label experiment
  var toPercent = d3.format("0.1%")
  
  //show travel points  
  /*var labelText = svg.selectAll(".labelText")
    .data(graph.links)
    .enter()
  .append("text")
    .attr("class","labelText")
    .attr("dx",130)
    .attr("dy",0)
  .append("textPath")
    .attr("xlink:href",function(d,i) { return "#linkLabel" + i;})
    .text(function(d,i) {                                 
    return d.source.name + " → " + d.target.name + " : " + d.value;})*/
/*    
// add the link titles
  link.append("title")
        .text(function(d) {
      return d.source.name + " → " + 
                d.target.name + "\n" + format(d.value); }); */

    
// add in the nodes
  var node = svg.append("g").selectAll(".node")
      .data(graph.nodes)
    .enter().append("g")
      .attr("class", "node")
      .attr("transform", function(d) { 
    return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; })
    .call(d3.behavior.drag()
      .origin(function(d) { return d; })
      .on("dragstart", function() { 
    this.parentNode.appendChild(this); })
      .on("drag", dragmove));
// add the rectangles for the nodes
  node.append("rect")
      .attr("height", function(d) { return d.dy; })
      .attr("width", sankey.nodeWidth())
      .style("fill", function(d) { 
    return d.color = color(d.name.replace(/ .*/, "")); })
      .style("stroke", function(d) { 
    return d3.rgb(d.color).darker(2); })
    .append("title")
      .text(function(d) { 
    return d.name + "\n" + format(d.value); });
// add in the title for the nodes
 node.append("text")
      .attr("x", -6)
      .attr("y", function(d) { return d.dy / 2; })
      .attr("dy", ".35em")
      .attr("text-anchor", "end")
      .attr("transform", null)
      .text(function(d) { return d.name + " : " + d.value + " : " + toPercent(d.value / total); })      //added d.value and % 
      .filter(function(d) { return d.x < width / 2; })
      .attr("x", 6 + sankey.nodeWidth())
      .attr("text-anchor", "start");
// the function for moving the nodes
  function dragmove(d) {
    d3.select(this).attr("transform", 
        "translate(" + d.x + "," + (
                d.y = Math.max(0, Math.min(height - d.dy, d3.event.y))
            ) + ")");
    sankey.relayout();
    link.attr("d", path);
  }
  

});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: I'm unclear what you're trying to do and I can't replicate your code without the csv and css files. Perhaps you could set up a jsfiddle.net to demonstrate. Plus your <head> tags look like they're in the wrong location and they should be lower case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to calculate the ratio of any node value over some `total`, so that each column sums to 100%.

You need to compute `total` by taking into account only source nodes (those which are not the target of any link), which should give the total you want. Replace your current formula for `total` with this one:

```
var total = d3.sum(graph.nodes, function(d) {
     if (d.targetLinks.length>0) 
        return 0; //node is not source, exclude it from the total
     else 
        return d.value; //node is a source: add its value to the sum
     });
```

It's hard to say more without a running example or a clear idea of what you want.